# Would love feedback on my latest project

Tags: design, feedback

Hey everyone, I'd love to get some feedback here for this short 27 second clip that I sound designed.

It is a piece I made for fun and then turned into a more serious work.  It is a redesign of a section of a trailer for a game called Child of Eden which this game originally is an interactive music game that you play with XBox motion sensor.

The graphics are so stunning and at times overwhelming that I had a hard time filling it in with my own sounds and having it fit.

It would be great if I could get some feedback on it because I want to finish it up and have it sound right and nice.
Almost all the sounds were made by me minus 3 or 4 whooshes that I added last minute from a stock library.

I also tried to keep the game somewhat musical and and aurally beautiful.

Still though I feel something may be missing or some parts may not be arranged the way they should be but I don't know why yet...the music is not my making and maybe I should take it out but it's only there for a few seconds..

> http://vimeo.com/31659476

Thanks in advance for taking a listen/look

Answer (score 1):

said page not found.

Answer (score 0):

I love the bell sound with the watery reverb and the opening section.  I think the last part needs some adjustments, all in all very unique sounds though.

Answer (score 0):

Nice pie e of work! I like the organic feel the sounds create, they support well the atmosphere the image is trying to create.

In second 6-7 the boy moves his hand as if he is throwing a power ball? This movement could maybe sported by a sound effect. I think this is an important section because sec 7 is just the transition point between the world of the boy and the world of the game, so you could use this effect to connect one scene with the other.

The sounds of the "bullets/shots" I think maybe could be more present and synchronized (a hell of a job to do...) What I understood from the image is that there are shots being fired at some organic shapes. This is the main idea the image wants to convey, so I would use the sound to reinforce this message. That is why I would give more importance to the sound and synchrony of the shots and use the other sound effects, which in my view work very well, to create a bed or ambiance.
As a little joke I would say that the last half a second sounds a bit like a flushing toilet :).

In over all its a nice piece of work and I hope to see more of you creations soon!!

All best

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Eric.  I was neglegent on too hard of an effect for the throwing the ball at first because I was hoping to have the two worlds blend together but on my last listen, I wanted something there so thats something you and I agree on.  I'll have to look at the bullets/shots mix/sound synchrony too, thanks.


Comment: Oh and the "toilet" at the end, yeah its not ACTUALLY a toilet, it's a water gurgle that is part of the BG/ATMOS but does sound like one! Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

I like your work, it seems like you invested a good amount of time in it.
The sound design (excluding music) is nice but a little underplayed. I actually liked your rough mix a bit better because you mixed them louder and that it feel more alive and firm. 
I agree with Eric about the syncing of the shot, overall this would help the image more.
The music is a bit distracting, i personally don't really like it, and i feel you could do with a little less, put your cards on the sound fx.

Nice job!